# i am able to use GET requests but can not figure out how to POST. I have added my git repo here if anyone could take a quick look?

Tags: javascript, json, api, post

Hello :) In my project I am able to do GET requests no problem but i can not figure POST out! here is a link to my repo where you will see the POST request i am trying to use at the very end of 'cart.js': https://github.com/josephabateman/Project5

it looks like this:

```
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras/order', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: contactObject, b: idStrings})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```

Comment: Which kind of error do you get??

Comment: you can view the request on the network tab on the dev tools. try to figure out the status code and response

Comment: Have you configured your server to handle [CORS preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)?

Comment: i get a 400 error

Answer (score 0):

From the endpoint, it requires a "contact" field in the body and some other fields.
the body should look something like.

```
(async () => {
  const body = {
    contact: {
      firstName: "Luke",
      lastName: "Moon",
      address: "Unknown",
      city: "Lagos",
      email: "gg@gmail.com"
    },
    products: []
  };
  const rawResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras/order', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
 });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

console.log(content);
})();
```

Try it out.

Comment: you genius!!! Thank you. I have hated my life today and you just turned it around :D ha. thanks again